# Laplace Transform using t-shift (second shift)

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

$$f(t) = tu(t-π)$$

I know I have to get t in terms of $$(t-π)$$ and to do that I have done

$$ t = a(t-π) + b$$
$$ t = at-aπ + b$$
$$ t = (a-π)t + b$$
$$ (a-π) = 1$$  and $$b = 0$$

Then I think I have done the write thing and being to t-shift with

$$ f(t) = (a-π)(t-π)u(t-π)$$ but when I apply the t-shift theorem I get lost. Is this the write method? have I done it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $*$ doesn't mean convolution in your original statement, note that 
$$tu(t-\pi) = (t-\pi + \pi)u(t-\pi) = (t-\pi)u(t-\pi) + \pi u(t-\pi)$$
Thus,

$$\mathcal{L}\{tu(t-\pi)\} = \mathcal{L}\{(t-\pi)u(t-\pi)\} + \pi\mathcal{L}\{u(t-\pi)\} = \ldots$$

Comment: Where do you do from there?

I got [1/s^2 - π/s]e^(-πs) + [π/s]e^(-πs)

but the answer is [1/s^2 + π/s]e^(-πs)

Comment: Apply the t-shift theorems.  You have that $\mathcal{L}\{(t-\pi)u(t-\pi)\} = e^{-\pi s}\mathcal{L}\{t\}$ and $\mathcal{L}\{u(t-\pi)\} = e^{-\pi s}\mathcal{L}\{1\}$.  Assuming that you've computed your Laplace transforms properly, you should get the answer the book provides.

Comment: Oh, I was doing L{(t−π)} instead of L{(t)}. I was treating (t-π) as f(t). Why is it your way? (I know you're right, I'm just trying to clear things up in my head!)

Comment: It more or less follows from the general statement of the shift theorem: 
$$\begin{aligned}\mathcal{L}\{f(t-a)u(t-a)\} &=\int_a^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t-a)\,dt \\ &= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-s(t+a)}f(t)\,dt \\ &= e^{-as}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t)\,dt \\ &= e^{-as}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\end{aligned}$$